# How do I repair my Motorola Defy rebooting instantly after start-up?

Tags: rom-flashing, reboot

I installed a few different operating systems (“ROMs”) on my Motorola Defy and I decided to (temporarily) go back to the original one, also known as “stock”, by using an SBF file. But now, whenever I try to start up my phone, it reboots almost instantly. I cannot do anything.

I tried booting in “Safe mode” as explained [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130808035801AAaRol3) (Power button + both volume keys). But that did not change anything. I also tried reflashing my SBF files multiple times, to no success.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery with Power button + lower volume key. Then, in the recovery mode menu, select “Factory reset”. This should delete all previous configurations from your previous ROMs that may interfere with your current installation.

Comment: That's a general rule when switching between different ROMs: Always make a wipe of at least cache and Dalvik. Sometimes, wiping `/data` is needed as well. Take the 3 together, and you have a factory-reset ;)

Comment: @Izzy it's generally a good rule in life, as well as Android flashing, to wipe thoroughly!